# How can I use "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH))" function with "TEXTJOIN" function in the same formula?

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need A NESTED FUNCTION  does the next:

1. Search in first sheet "case1" in column "c" about this value "mo"
   if it found it return this text "case1", if not doesn't return any thing(pic1)
2. Does the same function in second and third sheets: (pic2).
   Search in second sheet "case2" in column "c" about this value "mo"; if it found it return this text "case2", if not doesn't return anything
   Search in third sheet "case3" in column "c" about this value "mo"; if it found it return this text "case3", if not doesn't return anything
3. I want with it A TEXT FUNCTION  collect the results beside each other (pic3) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld5mF.jpg)

Comment: please share a dummy sheet with random data and desired output.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V4WgODaeQC3Ku_fFwUxDX2tw5n2o3UJXqBpGd-cgi-U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you give edit rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
=index(textjoin("+",1,if(isna({match("mo",case1!C:C,0),match("mo",case2!C:C,0),match("mo",case3!C:C,0)}),,"case"&sequence(1,3))))
```

**Update:**

```
=index(textjoin("+",1,if(isna({match("mo",case1!C:C,0),match("mo",above!C:C,0),match("mo",below!C:C,0)}),,{"case 1","above","below"})))
```

Comment: this is perfect but, can you make the text return as a text , just text not sequence 
because i will need to change this returned text

Comment: I updated the formula.